# Modal form submit using .one submits multiple if modal closed and reopened or validation catches missing input

Tags: c#, jquery

I've got a Modal called #fileModal.
A 'Create File' button calls initCreateFile.  This gets a form from an ajax call (c# PartialView) and loads the form into the #fileModal, and then shows the modal.
Second, eventFileValidation then creates a validation for the form.
Finally, submitCreateEventFile attaches a listener using .one to prevent multiple submissions.

There are some actions that seem to cause a multiple submissions.
First, closing the #fileModal, then reopening the modal with 'Create File', then submitting the form will cause a submissions equal to the amount times the modal was opened, with the most recent form data.
Second, if validation catches an error upon submission, then the user submits the form after fixing the validation error, it will submit multiple times.

I think what is happening is submitCreateEventFile is creating a listener each time initCreatefile is called.  Validation may be also calling this, but I'm not sure.  How can I prevent this from happening?

```
    submitCreateEventFile: function (modal) {
        
        $(modal).one("submit", "#create-event-file-form", function () {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var fileModal = $('#fileModal');
            closeModal(fileModal);
            var waitModal = $('#waitModal');
            initModal("", waitModal);
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: urls.eventfilecreate,
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            }).done(function (file) {
                
                closeModal(waitModal);
                eventFileApp.addFile(file);
            });
            $(this).on('submit', function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
            });
        })
    },
    initCreateFile: function (element) {
        var fileModal = $('#fileModal');
        initModal("Create Event File", fileModal);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: urls.eventfilecreate,
            data: { eventId: eventFileApp.getEventId(element) },
            traditional: true
        }).done(function (data) {
            setModalContents(fileModal, data);
            eventFileApp.eventFileValidation(fileModal);
            
            eventFileApp.submitCreateEventFile(fileModal);
        });
    },
    eventFileValidation: function (modal) {
        var form = modal.find('form');
        var isCreateForm = form.attr('id') == "create-event-file-form";
        form.validate({
            errorClass: "field-validation-error",
            rules: {
                Title: {
                    required: true
                },
                File: {
                    required: isCreateForm
                }
            },
            messages: {
                Title: {
                    required: "Title is required."
                },
                File: {
                    required: "File is required."
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding $('#fileModal').off('submit') prior to calling the validation and submit methods prevented duplicate event listeners from being adding.